# angularfire $watch() a property, not the entire object? (firebase, angular)

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Is there a way to watch when one property in an object changes? I tried

```
var unwatch = obj.$watch(function() {
  console.log("data changed");
});
```

That fired when any property in the object changes. I tried

```
var unwatch = obj.myProperty.$watch(function() {
  console.log("data changed");
});
```

That returned an error message: "TypeError: obj.myProperty.$watch is not a function".

I tried

```
var myTargetValue = $firebaseObject(ref.myProperty);
```

That returned an error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined".

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/81xy2kY335c

Comment: Thomas: I've landed here with the same issue, and spent a some time this morning writing up a more thorough, concise and explained answer. Please upvote my answer so future visitors can find it more easily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a `$firebaseObject` for the property. But, using the Firebase SDK tends to be more useful than `$watch()`.

**[JSBin Demo](https://jsbin.com/pucifanego/edit?js,console)**

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', 'https://34474165.firebaseio-demo.com/')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function MyController($scope, $firebaseObject, rootRef) {
  var objRef = rootRef.child('obj');
  var obj = $firebaseObject(objRef);
  var objMessage = $firebaseObject(rootRef.child('obj/message'));
  
  // watch the whole object
  var unwatch = obj.$watch(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
  });
  
  // watch a child property
  objMessage.$watch(function(a) {
    console.log(a, 'msg');
  });
  
  // get the whole object as it changes
  objRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    console.log(snap.val());
  });
  
  // get the child property as it changes
  objRef.child('message').on('value', function(snap) {
    console.log(snap.val());
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a feature that I saw on AirBnB. You enter data in a form, move your mouse out of the form, and a few seconds later a green animation comes up that says "Saved." I.e., I want to get rid of the "Submit" button on forms. Your answer gets me part way there:

Comment: $scope.targetCustomerDefinitionSaved = "";
    $firebaseObject(itemRef.child('targetCustomer1/targetCustomerDefinition')).$watch(function() {
      $scope.targetCustomerDefinitionSaved = "Saved";
    })

Comment: I'm setting `targetCustomerDefinitionSaved` as an empty string, so when you refresh the page nothing appears in the view. Then when you enter data in the field the value changes to "Saved", and the word "Saved" appears in the view.

Comment: `watch()` fires when the user enters new data in that field, and not when new data is entered in any other field. I.e., it's watching one value, not the entire object. So far, so good...

Comment: However, when you refresh the page it says "Saved" before you enter any data. :-(  To diagnose the problem I did this:

Comment: $scope.targetCustomerDefinitionSaved = "Foo";
    console.log($scope.targetCustomerDefinitionSaved);
    $firebaseObject(itemRef.child('targetCustomer1/targetCustomerDefinition')).$watch(function() {
      $scope.targetCustomerDefinitionSaved = "Saved";
      console.log($scope.targetCustomerDefinitionSaved);
    })

Comment: When I refresh the page the log shows "Foo", then other synchronous logs, then "Saved". Why is `watch()` firing when the page is refreshed, before the user enters any data?

Comment: And why are StackOverflow comments so short? :-)  And lack paragraph breaks?

Comment: This question should get upvoted. @ThomasDavidKehoe I think you may be looking to post your 6+ comments above as its own question, if you're still interested. I tried to provide a more concise and explained answer below.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer - Use vanilla Firebase (i.e. don't use Angularfire)

To watch a string, number or boolean property with Angularfire it's best to use vanilla Firebase:

```
// firebase reference
db = firebase.database().ref().child("myTable");

// watch the property
db.child("someProperty").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  $scope.message = snapshot.val();
});
```

#### Why not Angularfire, and $value:

Using `$firebaseObject` and passing in a reference to a primitive (string, number, boolean) returns an object like the following ([reference documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-value)):

```
{
  $id: "myProperty", 
  $priority: null, 
  $resolved: true, 
  $value: "Hi mom!"
}
```

In this example, the string I'm trying to watch is contained in the $value property of the returned object. I was inclined to assign the $value property to the `$scope`, however this wouldn't work:

```
// WONT WORK 
$scope.foo = $firebaseObject(db.child("myProperty")).$value;
```

There's a clash between Angular's object naming conventions and Firebase's object naming conventions that causes some trouble here. According to this ["Important Note"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-value) in the documentation, Angular's `$watch` function ignores properties with a `$` prefix. In other words, the view is not going to update if you assign the `$value` property of the returned object to `$scope`.

Thus, it's best to just use vanilla firebase to solve this problem (see top). Hope people find this helpful.